# How to place wxChoice in a wxGrid header?

Tags: header, grid, wxpython, controls

I'd like to creat a grid, in which user can change column name by wxchoice (or wxcombo) control.
I imagine it like this:
for example let user has tree columns of data

```
John,Smith,190
Maria,Kowalsky,180
```

I'd like to let user match each column to one of three options (firstname, lastname, height)
I'm at very beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import wx
from wx.grid import Grid

class DocsVarValGrid(Grid):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, init_data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocsVarValGrid, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.CreateGrid(1, 1)


        self.cols_names = init_data

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.panel = PickAFile(parent=self)
        self.grid = DocsVarValGrid(self, init_data=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App() # creation of the wx.App object (initialisation of the wxpython toolkit)
    frame = MyFrame(None, title="Hello World") # creation of a Frame with "Hello World" as title
    frame.Show() # frames are invisible by default so we use Show() to make them visible
    app.MainLoop() # here the app enters a loop waiting for user input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually do that. Instead you would have to draw a combobox yourself. This is allowed using the GridLabelRenderer mixin. At least, that's what is implied in the wxPython demo. If you don't already have that, I recommend downloading it and checking out the examples there. It doesn't actually have a combobox in that example, but I think it will get you going.

Comment: i've seen that example but i know too less to make it useful.
Mainly I don't know how to render wxchoice in MyRowLabelRenderer.Draw from Your example.

Comment: You should ask on the wxPython mailing list then. While I am pretty sure you can do this, I haven't done it myself. I'm sure the guys on that list can give you some pointers though.

Answer (score 0):

The column header window can be fetched from the grid using grid.GetGridColLabelWindow() and you can then do whatever you want with that window, such as override its paint event or placing widgets on it.  Take a look at the wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer module for some helper classes that would help you with overriding the drawing of the labels.

So while drawing a combobox-like thing yourself would be doable, in your case it would probably make most sense to just put a real widget there.  You will have to manage its size and position yourself, and adjust it every time the grid and/or columns are resized, but it should not be too overly difficult.  If you look in the gridlabelrenderer you will be able to see some code that calculates the rectangle that represents each label, and you can use something like that to resize and reposition your widget.